# Not able to List All keys avaiable in my Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to retrieve all keys that are saved in my key Vault using

```
keyVaultClient.GetKeyAsync(keyVaultVaultAddress).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

but getting below error

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

However I am able to get Key details by KeyURI using below code

```
keyVaultClient.GetKeyAsync(keyURI).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Can someone please help me in retrieving all keys that are saved in my Key Vault.

Thanks

Comment: Your code shows you trying to get the key listing with the single key get.  Is that a typing error? are you really trying it with the keyVaultClient.GetKeysAsync() ? Notice the 's' after Key.

Comment: ohh. I was in the impression that keyVaultClient.GetKeyAsync(keyVaultVaultAddress) will return me all keys if I just pass VaultAddress. Was not aware of another function GetKeysAsync with 's' that will return me all the keys.  Thanks you saved my day. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to restate what was in the comments for an answer (to help others locate in the future):

Instead of using the keyVaultClient.GetKeyAsync() that is used to get a single key, use the keyVaultClient.GetKeysAsync() - note the 's' after Key, to get a list of keys.